# Как сделать отображение шрифтов в IE

Tags: css

Для отображения нестандартных шрифтов используется @font-face

```
@font-face {
 font-family: gotham_reg;
 src: url('Content/fonts/GothaProReg.otf');
}

@font-face {
 font-family: gotham_bol;
 src: url('Content/fonts/GothaProBol.otf');
}

@font-face {
 font-family: open_sanslight;
 src: url('Content/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf');
}

@font-face {
 font-family: alt_got_no_3d;
 src: url('Content/fonts/AlternateGotNo3D-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
 font-family: open_sans_bold;
 src: url('Content/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
}
```

В Опере, Хроме, Мозилле, Сафари работает, а IE нет. Как сделать, чтобы в IE отображался нужный шрифт, а не стандартный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Браузер Internet Explorer до версии 9.0 поддерживает только шрифты формата EOT (Embedded OpenType).

Подключение шрифта должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
/* только для Internet Explorer */
@font-face {
 font-family: open_sanslight;
 src: url('Content/fonts/OpenSans-Light.eot');
}
/* далее для всех остальных браузеров */
@font-face {
 font-family: open_sanslight;
 src: url('Content/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf');
}
```

Поищите в интернете сервисы, где можно конвертировать ваш шрифт в формат EOT.

Один из [вариантов](http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi)